# How do I import text from a YAML file so it can be used as a struct in rust?

Tags: rust, discord, yaml

Me and my friend are making a Discord bot in Rust using the Serenity library. We have written the English translations for the bot messages in a YAML file. How can I implement it so the text in the YAML file can be used as a struct in Rust?

I have looked on the internet for instructions on how to do it, but either it does not work or I don't find what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [serde_yaml](https://crates.io/crates/serde_yaml) with serde's Derive feature to deserialize YAML into a struct. Example ([rust-playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=71c9386ee4eca7b236110e84b539c7f2)):

```rust
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, PartialEq, Debug)]
struct Point {
    x: f64,
    y: f64,
}

fn main() -> Result<(), serde_yaml::Error> {
    let yaml = "x: 1.0\ny: 2.0\n";
    let deserialized_point: Point = serde_yaml::from_str(&yaml)?;
    println!("{:?}", deserialized_point);
    Ok(())
}
```